# pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown transform large int to float

Tags: pandas, markdown, tabulate

`pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown` transforms large `int` to `float`. Is it a bug or a feature? Are there any solutions?

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [123456, 123456]})
>>> print(df.to_markdown())
|    |      A |
|---:|-------:|
|  0 | 123456 |
|  1 | 123456 |

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1234567, 1234567]})
>>> print(df.to_markdown())
|    |           A |
|---:|------------:|
|  0 | 1.23457e+06 |
|  1 | 1.23457e+06 |

>>> print(df)
         A
0  1234567
1  1234567

>>> print(df.A.dtype)
int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially found only a workaround, but not the explanation: converting the column to strings.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1234567, 1234567]})
>>> df["A"] = df.A.astype(str)
>>> print(df.to_markdown())
|    |       A |
|---:|--------:|
|  0 | 1234567 |
|  1 | 1234567 |
```

---

Update:

I think it is caused by 2 elements:

- The `_column_type` function in [`tabulate`](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/blob/master/tabulate.py):

```py
def _column_type(strings, has_invisible=True, numparse=True):
    """The least generic type all column values are convertible to.
```

It can be solved by disabling the conversion via `tablefmt="pretty"`:

```
print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt="pretty"))
+---+---------+
|   |    A    |
+---+---------+
| 0 | 1234567 |
| 1 | 1234567 |
+---+---------+
```

- When there are more than one column, and that one of them contains `float` numbers. Since `tabulate` uses `df.values` to extract the data, which transforms the `DataFrame` to `numpy.array`, all values are then converted to the same `dtype` (`float`). This is also discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/18).

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1234567, 1234567], "B": [0.1, 0.2]})
>>> print(df)
         A    B
0  1234567  0.1
1  1234567  0.2

>>> print(df.A.dtype)
int64

>>> print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt="pretty"))
+---+-----------+-----+
|   |     A     |  B  |
+---+-----------+-----+
| 0 | 1234567.0 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 1234567.0 | 0.2 |
+---+-----------+-----+

>>> df.values
array([[1.234567e+06, 1.000000e-01],
       [1.234567e+06, 2.000000e-01]])
```

Comment: I'll leave this answer unaccepted awhile to see if someone can provide a better answer than my own.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc mentions, the problem is with type conversion with tabulate and numpy. One way to fix this is to force numpy into using the "object" dtype, which will store everything in the numpy array as an object rather than coercing to a common datatype, then call tabulate manually:

```py
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1234567, 1234567], "B": [0.1, 0.2]})
>>> print(tabulate(df.to_numpy(dtype="object"), df.columns, tablefmt="pipe"))
|       A |   B |
|--------:|----:|
| 1234567 | 0.1 |
| 1234567 | 0.2 |
```

You may also format however you'd like:

```py
>>> print(tabulate(df.to_numpy(dtype="object"), df.columns, tablefmt="pipe", intfmt=",", floatfmt=".2f"))
|         A |    B |
|----------:|-----:|
| 1,234,567 | 0.10 |
| 1,234,567 | 0.20 |
```

See [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) for more options.